# Angular 2 pass data to modal component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

Inside my app component I have a table where a modal shows up when user clicks on any of the row. The modal contains details about the row. This is achieved by the following HTML code inside my component with the table.

```
<tr *ngFor="let myBug of myBugs" [attr.data-target]=" '#' + bugDetail.modalId" data-toggle="modal"
(click)="bugDetail.configureForm(myBug)">
<td>{{ myBug.title }}</td>
```

However, the problem with this approach is that the data is passed after ngOnInit has completed. Therefore, If do something like the following inside myModal.component.html, the app will crash as the value is undefined at first.

```
{{myBug.title}} // This is inside myModal.component.html
```

I understand that I could do the following to get rid of the error. However, I do not want to do this as the modal should be generated with the data from the clicked table-row

```
{{myBug?.title}}
```

So I have tried adding the following code inside my modal component

```
@Input() bugInputTest
```

And in my table HTML code, I change to the following

```
<tr 
    *ngFor="let myBug of myBugs" 
    [attr.data-target]=" '#' + bugDetail.modalId" 
    data-toggle="modal"
    (click)="bugDetail.configureForm(myBug)">
    <td>{{ myBug.title }}</td>
</tr>

<modal-approval-detail #bugDetail [bugInputTest]="myBug"></modal-approval-detail>
```

and inside ngOnInit() inside my modal component, I put

```
console.log(this.bugInputTest)
```

to see if the data gets passed in. As you can predicted this does not work and generated undefined inside my console. I think I can see that the problem comes from [bugInputTest]="myBug" as myBug isn't accessible outside the for loop where the  tags are...

How can I pass data from my main component to the modal component in Angular2?

Answer (score 1):

In Modal Component
You need to write configurationForm method

```
 @ViewChild('myModal')
    modal: ModalComponent;
    @Input() bugInputTest : MyBug
    public configureForm(myBug : MyBug)void {
            this.bugInputTest = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myBug));
            this.modal.open();
    }
```